# data role page dynamic display

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am creating a HTML page with multiple data-role pages.loading time we will check some condition and display that particular data-role page.currently id display first data-role, how can i display data role page conditionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html) section "autoInitializePage". Here you can disable the default initialization `until $.mobile.initializePage is manually called`.

> [Because the mobileinit event is triggered immediately, you'll need to
>   bind your event handler before jQuery Mobile is loaded. Link to your
>   JavaScript files in the following order:](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html)
>   jquery.js
>   custom-scripting.js
>   jquery-mobile.js

Please take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZC6uA/8/). What it basibally does is adding a hash to your url thus redirecting to the subpage.

[Source](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/dynamically-selection-a-start-page)

Comment: Fiddle is now online. I do not know your conditions so I am selecting the page randomly.